# Do event on JButton Click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

So I have created a swing GUI that is a board (n by n) that contains n^2 blocks(buttons). The breakdown of the code is like so: create GUI (Jframe and Jpanel) -> create Board (array of NxN blocks) -> create blocks(JButton). Once the board is created I generate and maze and its show each button with the proper border etc. My issue is that I want an action to be performed when a button is clicked.
This is the GUI class

EDIT: To clarify, my question is: How do I implement my block (Jbutton) to do an event on click. Also, want to be able to obtain the Block object so that I can manipulate it.

```
public class GUI {

    private int width;
    private int height;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Color color;
    private JPanel panel;
    private GridLayout layout;
    private Board board;

    static final Color PLAYER = Color.BLUE;
    static final Color OPEN = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    static final Color OCCUPIED = Color.ORANGE;

    public GUI(int width, int height, Color color){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        frame = new JFrame("2D MAP");
        this.color = color;
        panel = new JPanel();
        layout = new GridLayout(width,height);
        board = new Board(width,height);
        board.populate();
    }
```

This is the Board class

```
public class Board {
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int x; // Random X coordinate to start
    private int y; // Random Y coordinate to start
    private Map<String, Integer> dx = Map.of("N", -1, "S", 1, "E", 0, "W", 0);
    private Map<String, Integer> dy = Map.of("N", 0, "S", 0, "E", -1, "W", 1);
    private Map<String, String> oppositeDir = Map.of("N", "S", "S", "N", "E", "W", "W", "E");
    private String[] directions = new String[]{"N", "S", "E", "W"};
    Block[][] board;

    public Board(int width, int height){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.x = rand.nextInt(this.height);
        this.y = rand.nextInt(this.width);
        board = new Block[width][height];
    }
```

And finally this is the Block class aka the button

```
public class Block{

    private int topBorder = 1, leftBorder = 1, rightBorder = 1, botBorder = 1;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private JButton button;
    private Color color;
    private String type;
    private Map<String, Block> neighbors;

    public Block(int x, int y, JButton button, Color color, String type){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.color = color;
        this.button = new JButton();
        this.type = type;
        this.neighbors = new HashMap<String, Block>();
    }
```

Comment: But what is the question?

Comment: How do i implement on block(Jbutton) click event

Answer (score 0):

To add button actions to buttons you simply have to add `ActionListener` to a button via `addActionListener` method

```
this.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        

void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
   //handle button click
   }
}
```

Comment: In which file would I add this method. In GUI, Block, Board, or my Main?

Comment: whereve you got your buttons.